# Bootstrap DateTime Picker set seconds to 00

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using  bootstrap datetime picker in my application. I am using the format like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss", results are like "2015-07-09 12:25:12", but I want to set ":00" in place of seconds so that my new date format become like "2015-07-09 12:25:00". I have tried below code but seconds field is missing. It is showing like "2015-07-09 12:25".

```
directives.directive('tgdatetimepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            format: "mm-dd-yyyy  hh:ii:00",
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
          }).on('setDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `mm-dd-yyyy  hh:ii:[00]` as the format pattern.

Assuming you are talking about this [bootstrap-datetimepicker library](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker), these [formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) apply.

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Comment: I have tried same thing. But it is not showing seconds field like "2015-07-09 12:25".

Comment: Updated my answer, used wrong escape char. [source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But same problem.

Comment: I have changed  bootstrap-datetimepicker  click function 'date.getSeconds() to 0' . Now it is working fine. But keydown function is not working.

Comment: thats a different question

Comment: Not able to set 00 as seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You van add an ng-change method that set seconds to 0 when the date is modified.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions, use the changeDate event but apply the change after 300 ms. This work for me.

```
$('#from_date').datetimepicker({
    toggleActive: true,                                
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:ss',                                
    autoclose: true,
    pickTime: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
    firstDayOfWeek: 'Date.Mon'
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        let curDate = $('#from_date').val();
        let resetDate = moment(curDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:[00]');                             
        $('#from_date').val(resetDate);
    }, 300)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  timeFormat: "hh:mm:00",  useLocalTimezone: false`

Force seconds to '00' anywhere^^